# Add views to existing layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an xml layout and all is fine. Upon a button click I want to show more buttons on the layout. What is the right way of doing this? Right now I create the buttons on the same xml and set their visibility to GONE. Once button is clicked and set their visibility to VISIBLE.

Is this a correct way of doing things? The layout is getting a bit complicated with other image views following the same pattern

Thank you so much

Comment: extract your layout in <include /> and show hide your include tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off: I am not sure why someone gave you a down to the question, as it is pretty straight forward and clear.

Now the answer.

So, the whole thing, in order to be properly "made" ,should be done programmatically.
 Before I will give you some written code (as example), I will explain you a bit how you should look at this.

You have your main XML file in which you have that button which you want to click and upon clicking, make more buttons appear on the screen.Well, in order to achieve this, creating buttons and make them INVISIBLE or VISIBLE depending on the need, is NOT really a good way to deal with it.You might wounder why? Well, it's clearly not a good way because even though your buttons are invisible ,when the application starts, the buttons ,even though being invisible ,they are being created (drawn).And this will take space and slow the application.

Say you want to be able to create an indeterminate number of buttons, upon click your first button.Well, you cannot even achieve this by the way you described in your question.You really limit yourself by using the XML so much.

The SOLUTION:

So, you have your XML file, in which you have your layout (relative or linear,does not matter for now) and your button which when is pressed creates a button.

In order to be able to get reference to your XML Layout and your Button ,you need to give them an ID.And you do this inside the XML (I am pretty sure you know that,but I prefer writing full explications).

Giving ID to the layout:

```
   android:id="@+id/thelayout"
```

Giving ID to the layout:

```
   android:id="@+id/button"

(If you don't know where to add those IDs, comment it,I will help further)
```

Now that you can refer to the layout and the button from java, this is where it gets fun.

You define a layout and a button.NOTE: Check your XML file!!! If you have a RelativeLayout ,you need to define a RelativeLayout ,if you have a LinearLayout...well is clear.

I am going to assume we got a LinearLayout.

```
 LinearLayout ll;
 Button btn;
 Button thenewbutton;

 ll= (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.thelayout);  //The name we gave in XML
 btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

 What we need to do now, is to add a method which will do something when we click the buttom.

 btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Here we will handle the creation of the button;

            thenewbutton = new Button(getActivity()); //Created the new button
            thenewbutton.setText("One of the new buttons"); //Setted it the text in between the ""            
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Making it visible -like you were doing prolly.

            //You can customize your button via methods.Write "thenewbutton." and eclipse will show you all the methods you can use in order to "play" with the new created button.

            //Now, the button is created.All we need to do is to add it to the layout!Easy job.                

            ll.addView(thenewbutton);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And this is it ,pretty much.

I have explained it as detailed as I could.I know is a lot to read, but if you wanna truly understand, than take the 3-5 minutes to read and really go through everything I wrote and you will have another level of understanding the problem.

If you need further help, leave a comment!

Cheers!

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add -you can do the exact same thing with imageViews.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. This is very nice of you. Really the key point I was looking for here is the explanation you made in the beginning. The rest I know but didn't think about using. But it would be good for someone who is new and searching for answers. +1 and Accepted :)

Comment: I just find it harder to "position" views using code as apposed to xml. That's all. I was wondering if there is another well known method where you can do you "secondary" layer of drawing in another xml and then superimpose it on your main xml

Comment: In order to positon a view from java , you have to "setLayoutParameters".