# Button that adds layout widgets to your activity Kotlin android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to create a task application, like Google Tasks for example.

And in Google Tasks, there's a plus button (attached image) that's when it, a new layer with checkbox and ext appears.
[button adds new check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeC43.jpg)
The question is how can I recreate that. Does the new CB has an Id? can it handle click events? how can I save it in things like SharedPerfences so it will remain for later?
Another short question, that I feel linked to the previous, is can I define in 1 variable all the widget in the activity that's are CheckBoxes, for example ( and not by manually array or list).
pls answers in Kotlin. Thanks!

I couldn't find ANY answers to my question in Google, so im putting it here.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your first question:
If you want a view to appear after a click event on another view you should set the visibility of the first one to GONE in your xml, then in your activity/fragment you can handle the click event on the triggering view, setting the visibility of the view you want to appear to VISIBLE.

Something like this:

Hidden view initial status xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

Then in your activity/fragment:

```
binding.triggeringView.setOnClickListener {
    binding.checkbox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: its quite doing this, but can you CREATE checkbox? (for effective code and performence)

Comment: Yes, you can do that programmatically, refer to this for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183136/add-views-to-existing-layout
BUT, in my opinion you have a better control over the view if you only have to manage one single attribute(=visibility) instead of managing the whole creation-of-a-new-view.
Furthermore, speaking of code effectiveness and performance, setting a view to GONE is not the same as INVISIBLE: in the latter case the view, whilst being invisible, is actually drawn into the layout (taking space etc), the GONE view isn't.